# Using a default value between two different build gradle files

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have the following scenario in my Android project:

Project1 --> Build.gradle (1)
    Project2--> Build.gradle (2)

```
Example: Define the following variable:

//first Gradle file
def getProductFlavor() {
//Logic here
Gradle gradle = getGradle()
String requestingTask = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()
return requestingTask
}

Instead of defining getCurrentTime() in the second Gradle file, 
I call the getCurrentTime() from the first Gradle file.
```

Maybe my example is wrong and the default value needs to be implementing in another gradle file like the script gradle or somewhere else, but the intent of the example was to clarify what I'm trying to achieve.

**The two projects are independents but both belong to the same android project. I want to use ONE def value in both of these gradle files.**

I'm a gradle newbie by the way. Never mind if I'm asking this question the wrong way.

Comment: does this value you need to get in both projects require some environment info or it is independent from both projects?

Comment: Yes. So I need to get the current product flavor. I'm defining the product flavors in the first build gradle file using productFlavors {A, B, C, ..ect}.

Comment: can you explain in more details what code is inside this common method?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker added logic for getProductFlavor().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feels like a scenario for external script:

```
main-project
....| sub-project1
........| src
........| build.gradle
....| sub-project2
........| src
........| build.gradle
....| common.gradle
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply from: '../common.gradle'

def flavor = getProductFlavor()
```

**common.gradle**

```
def getProductFlavor() {
    Gradle gradle = getGradle()
    String requestingTask = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()
    return requestingTask
}

ext {
    getProductFlavor = this.&getProductFlavor
}
```

Comment: It's returning "Invalid value to assign to" for the "getProductFlavor" when added in the ext bracket inside common.gradle.